# Fail to install CUDA, Flux, CuArrays etc, pls advise - Julia packages

Tags: julia, gpu, flux.jl

I am new to Julia, when trying to add `CUDA`, comes the error as following.
It seems meaning the `CuArrays` is not in right condition, so I add the `CuArrays` from the github, then it comes another error about `Adapt`.
When adding `Adapt`, it seems fine, but when rolling back, the `Adapt` issue comes again.
Just like rabbit holes in Alice's dream, I am stucked here and don't know what to do to make it work.
Please advise, Thanks,

BTW, the CUDA path is set.

```
OS:Win10
JuliaPro 1.5.0
GPU: NVIDIA MX150
```

**CUDA.jl**

```
(@JuliaPro_v1.5.0-1) pkg> add https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDA.jl
   Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDA.jl`
  Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package CUDAnative [be33ccc6]:
 CUDAnative [be33ccc6] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.7.0, 0.8.0-0.8.10, 0.9.0-0.9.1, 0.10.0-0.10.1, 1.0.0-1.0.1, 2.0.0-2.0.1, 2.1.0-2.1.3, 2.2.0-2.2.1, 2.3.0-2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.5.0-2.5.5, 2.6.0, 2.7.0, 2.8.0-2.8.1, 2.9.0-2.9.1, 2.10.0-2.10.2, 3.0.0-3.0.4, 3.1.0, 3.2.0] or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions [0.7.0, 0.8.0-0.8.10, 0.9.0-0.9.1, 0.10.0-0.10.1, 1.0.0-1.0.1, 2.0.0-2.0.1, 2.1.0-2.1.3, 2.2.0-2.2.1, 2.3.0-2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.5.0-2.5.5, 2.6.0, 2.7.0, 2.8.0-2.8.1, 2.9.0-2.9.1, 2.10.0-2.10.2, 3.0.0-3.0.4, 3.1.0, 3.2.0]
 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with LLVM [929cbde3] to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
   └─LLVM [929cbde3] log:
     ├─possible versions are: [0.9.0-0.9.15, 1.0.0, 1.1.0-1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.3.0-1.3.4, 1.4.0-1.4.1, 1.5.0-1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 2.0.0, 3.0.0] or uninstalled
     └─restricted to versions 3 by CUDA [052768ef], leaving only versions 3.0.0
       └─CUDA [052768ef] log:
         ├─possible versions are: 1.3.0 or uninstalled
         └─CUDA [052768ef] is fixed to version 1.3.0
```

**CUDAnative**

```
(@JuliaPro_v1.5.0-1) pkg> add https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDAnative.jl
   Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDAnative.jl`
  Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Adapt [79e6a3ab]:
 Adapt [79e6a3ab] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 2.3.0 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions [0.4, 1] by CUDAnative [be33ccc6] — no versions left
 │ └─CUDAnative [be33ccc6] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: 3.1.0 or uninstalled
 │   └─CUDAnative [be33ccc6] is fixed to version 3.1.0
 └─Adapt [79e6a3ab] is fixed to version 2.3.0
```

**Adapt**

```
(@JuliaPro_v1.5.0-1) pkg> add https://github.com/JuliaGPU/Adapt.jl
   Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaGPU/Adapt.jl`
  Resolving package versions...
No Changes to `C:\Users\eric1\.julia\environments\JuliaPro_v1.5.0-1\Project.toml`
No Changes to `C:\Users\eric1\.julia\environments\JuliaPro_v1.5.0-1\Manifest.toml`
```

[image: CUDA Path]
[image: GPU running]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be installing packages:

```
(@JuliaPro_v1.5.0-1) pkg> add CUDA
```

If you are doing instead `add https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDA.jl` you are installing the latest development version (master branch) from the repository.
Since it is a development  (current-state-of-source-code) version quite likely something might not work.

Now, I recommend you to remove all those dev package versions that you have installed (so run `rm` package manager commad) and then reinstall their release versions rather than dev versions.

There is a good change that after that you will not have a dependency clash.

Comment: let me know if it helped!

Comment: I decided to re-install julia, and start all over again, Since I am new and the cost is limited.

Comment: It is alway just enough to delete and reinstall whatever your JULIA_DEPOT_PATH is pointing to (or setting it to a new location)